# Required Navigation Drawer Layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I tried using Android Translate, Rotate and Scale options to design a navigation drawer as attached sample, but no success. Can anyone please help me how I can design this and what I am suppose to use.

Thanks in Advance.

[image: Navigation Menu]

Comment: check here on how to animate the content view when you open the drawer -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20081660/how-to-make-background-activity-smaller-while-opening-the-navigation-drawer

Comment: the second answer from the above link also includes a library link which looks exactly what you want -- https://github.com/SpecialCyCi/AndroidResideMenu

Comment: Thanks a lot @Tasos, I will definitely try this.